# NodeJS :: TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I was learning the MEAN stack from a tutorial. When I tried on my localhost, I got an error.

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined**
>
> **at router.post (/var/www/html/mean/contactlist/routes/route.js:17:28)**

I found some similar questions on the internet. But I didn't find the correct solution.

Here is my **app.js** file

```
//importing modules
var express =  require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path'); //core module 


// calling express method
var app = express(); 


//connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/27017/contactlist');

//on connection
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log("connected to database database mongodb @ 27017 ");
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {

    if(err){
        console.log('Error in Database connection : ' + err);
    }
});

//adding middleware cors
app.use(cors());

//adding body parser
app.use(bodyparser.json());

//adding static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//setting port no 
const port = 3000;


//routing
var route = require('./routes/route'); 

//using the route
app.use('/api', route); 


//testing server
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{

    res.send('foobar');

});

//binding the server with port no (callback)

app.listen(port,() =>{
    console.log('Server Started at Port : '+ port);


});
```

From a stackOverflow solution, I found,

I should use the following line before **routing**

```
app.use(bodyparser.json());
```

So I changed it.

And my **./routes/route.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Contact = require('../models/contacts');

//Retrieving contacts
router.get('/contacts', (res, req, next) => {
    contact.find(function(err,contacts){
        res.json(contacts);
    })

});

//Add contact
router.post('/contact', (res, req, next) => {
    let newContact = new Contact({
        first_name:req.body.first_name,
        last_name:req.body.last_name,
        phone:req.body.phone
    });

    

    newContact.save((err,contact) => {

        if(err){
            res.json({msg : 'Failed to add contact'});
        }
        else{
           res.json({msg : 'Contact added successfully'}); 
        }

    });
});


//Deleting Contact
router.delete('/contact/:id', (res, req, next) => {
    contact.remove({_id: req.params.id }, function(err, result){

        if(err){
            res.json(err);
        }
        else{
            res.json(result);
        }

    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

**Dependencies** from **package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.3",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.8"
  }
```

And the version of the nodejs is

```
v7.10.0
```

I used Postman to test the API

So I tested with POST method and following content-type option.

```
 {"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
```

This was my sample input

```
{ 
   "first_name" : "RENJITH",
   "last_name"  : "VR",
   "phone" :  "1234567890"
}
```

Is it a version issue? Please suggest me the correct way of coding.

Comment: Where you can get this error? In this error you always get file and line..

Comment: @NedimHozić - `first_name:req.body.first_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your content type is `{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}`
In order to support URL-encoded bodies of data you need to use this:

```
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));
```

What you used is for JSON-encoded data, such as `POST: {"name":"foo","color":"red"}`

EDIT:

The order of your route parameters are wrong. It's not `router.post('/contact', (res, req, next)`

It's actually `router.post('/contact', (req, res, next)`

The first parameter is the request, the second is the response.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I think it was `bodyparser`. Not `bodyParser` . Right? And I tried. It is not working!

Comment: You defined your variable bodyparser, so you should use that. I edited my post to reflect that. Add the code I mentioned, but with bodyparser instead of bodyParser, and try to send the request again. (make sure you restarted your server). It should work.

Comment: If you set your Content-Type header to "application/json" in Postman, it should work without even needing to add the urlencoded middleware.

Comment: I'm using nodemon. So I don't need to restart the server. Right?

Comment: Oh, the parameters of your function are in the wrong order. Switch the order of res and req and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Just Move lines body-parse at the top before route (app.js)

```
app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.use('/api',route);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue but this is how it's been solved for me

At the top of the file before any routes and after `require` statements use

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

then in the post request route use `res.json()`

here is sample code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + './index.html')
})

app.post("/name", (req, res) => {
    let fullName = req.body.first + ' ' + req.body.last;
    res.json({ name: fullName }) 
});
```